# FileZilla Fails When Attempting SFTP Connection that Aren't KeyFile-based Connections

Tags: windows-11, amazon-ec2, filezilla

Having worked for years and successfully connecting to Amazon EC2 instances via a local Ubuntu 20.04 environment, I've recently switched to Windows 11 Pro.

When trying to connect to Amazon EC2 instances via FileZilla, using the variables and settings I've used for years and provided below, I'm met with the following output:

```
Status: Connecting to <-redacted->.amazonaws.com...

Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=11

Command:    open "<-redacted->" 22

Status: Using username "<-redacted->". 

Error:  Could not connect to server
```

What's puzzling is the following:

- **Key File Connections Work:** I can connect with KeyFile-based connections just fine, just as the same as I always have. I punch in the host, password, port 22, etc. the same as I would an "Ask for Password" or "Normal" connection type and it works brilliantly.
- **PuTTY with the same credentials works perfectly:** I can use PuTTY, using the same port, username, password -- everything -- and connect to the server just fine.

---

**[Local Environment]**

- Windows 11 Pro

**[Connecting Server Environment]**

- Amazon Linux 2 on Amazon EC2
- Using custom security group with ports 80 and 443 open to http and https traffic, with SSH port 22 open to my IP only

**[FileZilla Settings]**

- Running as administrator in Windows 11
- Protocol: SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol
- Host: <-redacted->, but the very same one I've used for years connecting from a Linux environment.
- Logon Type: Ask for Password
- User: <-redacted->, but like the host, the same one I've always used.

[**What I've Attempted**]

- **Temporarily setting the allowed connection on port 22 (on the server) to ALL ips**: This was to see if it was somehow blocking my IP. Nope. Still got the same error. This was immediately changed back to only my IP.
- **Setting FileZilla to Active Mode**: I've set FileZilla to Active, back to Passive, and nothing here has seemed to work.
- **Setting an Inbound and Outbound Port 22 Connection to "Open"**: Getting desperate, I've been trying to open any form of port 22 on my local machine -- inbound and outbound -- just to try to get any kind of connection established other than KeyFile connections.
- **Completely shut off Windows Firewall, Defender, etc.**: I've disabled everything I could think of and tried to clear the way for any port 22 connections.
- **Clearing the *trustedcerts.xml* file**: This was located at `%APPDATA%\FileZilla` per the following thread; I cleared out everything and started fresh: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849566/filezilla-error-could-not-connect-to-server
- **Checked and re-checked my passwords, usernames, etc.**
- **Set up new SFTP "Ask for Password" and "Normal" connections to the server without specifying port or password**

[**Results of Those Attempts**]

Everything I've tried results in the same error:

```
Status: Connecting to <-redacted->.amazonaws.com...

Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=11

Command:    open "<-redacted->" 22

Status: Using username "<-redacted->". 

Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Comment: Have you seen the FileZilla article [How to Resolve the Critical Error “Could not Connect to Server”](https://filezillapro.com/docs/v3/troubleshooting/critical-error-could-not-connect-to-server/)? Maybe the network configuration wizard will help.

Comment: it's a filezilla problem, upgrade your client.